# Finding the minimum and maximum values in a std::vector of std::pair

Tags: c++, vector, max, min, std-pair

I'm trying to find out the minimum and maximum value in a vector of `pair<int, std::string>`.

**My Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> pairs;
    pairs = {{6,"a"}, {4,"b"}, {5,"c"}, {8,"d"}, {7,"e"}};

    int min = 0, max = 0;

    // How can I find out the minimum and maximum?

    std::cout << "Minimum Number: " << min << '\n';
    std::cout << "Maximum Number: " << max << '\n';
}
```

**The result I want:**

```
Minimum Value: 4
Maximum Value: 8
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

How can I get the result I want?

---

Here's my solution so far.

```
std::sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end());
min = pairs[0].first;
max = pairs[pairs.size()-1].first;
```

Although it works, I would like to learn a simpler and faster solution than this.

Comment: Looking at [<algorithm>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) might be a good first step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might use `std::minmax_element`:

```
 const auto p = std::minmax_element(pairs.begin(), pairs.end());
 auto min = p.first->first;
 auto max = p.second->first;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Is this faster than my own solution?

Comment: Complexity is `O(n)` whereas your is `O(n log n)`. (and it uses even less comparisons than `std::min_element` followed by `std::max_element`).

Comment: Or with C++17: `auto&& [min, max] = std::minmax_element(begin(pairs), end(pairs));` for brevity.

Comment: @Deduplicator: There is still the `std::pair<int, std::string>::first` to call.