# Find max/min value of a member class in a container

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have a vector/container of classes and I want to find the element that has the max/min value of a specific member; for example:

```
#include <vector>

struct A {
    int val;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<A> v{{1},{2},{3}};

    // how do I find the maximum of .val inside the vector?
}
```

Is there an "STL" way to find the item without explicitly iterating over the container and compare the values?

### A comment on the two solutions

I'll add here a solution based on @Jarod42 comment on the accepted solution, based on std::ranges::less{} :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct A {
    int val1;
    int val2;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> v{{6,8}, {4,10}, {5,12}};

    // How can I find out the minimum and maximum?
    const auto [min, max] = std::ranges::minmax_element(v, std::ranges::less{}, &A::val1);
    std::cout << "Minimum Number: " << min->val1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "Maximum Number: " << max->val1 << '\n';
}
```

I prefer this solution when the comparison to determine the min/max value is trivial, while the accepted solution is more generic and can be used when the definition of "less than" is complex.

Not sure if it needs C++20's ranges, but I'm using C++20 anyway so for the moment I won't investigate it any further.

Comment: [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the minimum and maximum values in a std::vector of std::pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52095586/finding-the-minimum-and-maximum-values-in-a-stdvector-of-stdpair)

Comment: @Borgleader partly: in that question it works because std::pair has defined the < operator to make the comparison; otherwise you have to pass a comparison function object - like a lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways:

- [`std::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min)
- [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element)

For example:

```
auto smallest = std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const A v1, const A v2) {
      return v1.val < v2.val;
});
    
std::cout << "Smallest: " << smallest->val << "\n";
```

Comment: [`std::ranges::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/min) (C++20) `std::ranges::min(v, std::ranges::less{}, &A::val);`

Comment: BTW, OP asks for **max** ;-)